# how to retrieve profile Id with DotnetOpenAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetopenauth

How to retrieve profile Id with DotnetOpenAuth 
to get the data from google Analytics API.

I got the oAuth Token But when tried to retrieve data using this token,
I got the Exception -- Execution Failed Error.

```
The request 'Google.Apis.Requests.Request(list @ https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists?alt=json&prettyPrint=true)' has failed. The service tasks has thrown an exception: Google.GoogleApiRequestException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at Google.Apis.Requests.Request.InternalEndExecuteRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) in c:\google\6-21-2012\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\Request.cs:line 327
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Google.Apis.Requests.Request.AsyncRequestResult.GetResponse() in c:\google\6-21-2012\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\Request.cs:line 301
  at Google.Apis.Requests.ServiceRequest`1.GetResponse() in c:\google\6-21-2012\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ServiceRequest.cs:line 183
  at Google.Apis.Requests.ServiceRequest`1.Fetch() in c:\google\6-21-2012\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ServiceRequest.cs:line 203
  at GoogleAnalyticsNew._Default.FetchTaskslists() in E:\Anagha\GA\GoogleAnalyticsNew\GoogleAnalyticsNew\Default.aspx.cs:line 186
```

Can any one please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should be asking for information with your API key, like so:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists/test?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

You can play around with the Tasks API [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/tasks/v1/tasks.tasklists.get).

If you don't know your API key, you can find it in the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/).